# Toggle class except on the current clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `toggleClass()` function to add a class to remaining `.members-section` div elements. It's working fine but the class is being added to the currently clicked div also. How can I apply the class to elements except the clicked on in jQuery?

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#as-member').click(function(e) {
    $('.members-section').toggleClass('unselected');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="members-section" id="as-member">
  <img src="img/test1.jpg" alt="">
  <span>Join as a new member</span>
</div>
<div class="members-section" id="as-student">
  <img src="img/test2.jpg" alt="">
  <span>Join as a student</span>
</div>
<div class="members-section">
  <img src="img/test3,jpg" alt="">
  <span>Upgrade my membership</span>
</div>
<div class="members-section test-members" >
  <h5>Teest...</h5>
  <ul class="member-options">
    <li><span>Discounts</span></li>
    <li><span>Institute access</span></li>
    <li><span>Library access</span></li>
    <li><span>Market events</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not(this)` for that. It filters out the currently clicked element out of the jQuery selection.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#as-member, #as-student').click(function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('unselected').siblings().addClass('unselected');
  });
});
```

```css
.unselected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="members-section " id="as-member"><img src="img/test1.jpg" alt="">
  <span>Join as a new member</span>
</div>
<div class="members-section " id="as-student"><img src="img/test2.jpg" alt="">
  <span>Join as a student</span>
</div>
<div class="members-section "><img src="img/test3,jpg" alt="">
  <span>Upgrade my membership</span>
</div>
<div class="members-section">
  <h5>Teest...</h5>
  <ul class="member-options">
    <li><span>Discounts</span></li>
    <li><span>Institute access</span></li>
    <li><span>Library access</span></li>
    <li><span>Market events</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can we use another not with class?

Comment: In the above code, I edited, test-members should not toggle

Comment: @jafarpinjar yes the not function works with all kind of selectors. `not(".test-members")` filters out all elements with the class `test-member`.

Comment: I have written click action for other div also, in that scenario its failing, can you pls update me the code to toggle other div click action also

Comment: @jafarpinjar Not sure what you meant but updated the code to also exclude `#as-student`. If that's not what you want i recommend to open a new question and describe your problem in detail.

Comment: that is not my question.@mark, i need to write click event for as-student id also, if so, the other div is not toggled as expected

Comment: @jafarpinjar Added the same handler to the as-student and changed the toggleClass to remove the class from the selected element and add the class to it's siblings. I think that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

use `.not($(this))` to achieve

```
$('.members-section').not($(this)).toggleClass('unselected');
```

```css
.unselected{
background-color:#0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="members-section " id="as-member">
        <img src="img/test1.jpg" alt="">
        <span>Join as a new member</span>
    </div>
    <div class="members-section " id="as-student">
        <img src="img/test2.jpg" alt="">
        <span>Join as a student</span>
    </div>
    <div class="members-section " id="as-test">
        <img src="img/test3,jpg" alt="">
        <span>Upgrade my membership</span>
    </div>
    <div class="members-section" id="as-four">
        <h5>
            Teest...</h5>
        <ul class="member-options">
            <li><span>Discounts</span></li>
            <li><span>Institute access</span></li>
            <li><span>Library access</span></li>
            <li><span>Market events</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function ($) {
                $('#as-member').click(function (e) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('active-div')) {
                        $('.members-section').removeClass('unselected active-div');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.members-section').removeClass('unselected');
                        $(this).removeClass('unselected').addClass('active-div').siblings().addClass('unselected').removeClass('active-div');
                        $('#as-four').removeClass('unselected');
                    }
                });

                $('#as-student').click(function (e) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('active-div')) {
                        $('.members-section').removeClass('unselected active-div');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.members-section').removeClass('unselected');
                        $(this).removeClass('unselected').addClass('active-div').siblings().addClass('unselected').removeClass('active-div');

                        $('#as-four').removeClass('unselected');
                    }
                });

                $('#as-test').click(function (e) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('active-div')) {
                        $('.members-section').removeClass('unselected active-div');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.members-section').removeClass('unselected');
                        $(this).removeClass('unselected').addClass('active-div').siblings().addClass('unselected').removeClass('active-div');

                        $('#as-four').removeClass('unselected');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi @Ushay, once the div clicked the other can not be clicked,

Comment: now the above code works correctly, but when clicked next div, toggle unselected not working as expected

Comment: do you want click event for all div's

Comment: yes, in that case we should not allow other div to click until its toggled class reverted

Comment: I am writing click action for as-student , so in this scenario toggle not working as expected

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you can use `not()` to exclude the `.members-section` which was clicked:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var $sections = $('.members-section').click(function(e) {
    $sections.not(this).toggleClass('unselected');
  });
});
```

```css
.members-section {
  color: #000;
}
.members-section.unselected {
  color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="members-section" id="as-member">
  <img src="img/test1.jpg" alt="">
  <span>Join as a new member</span>
</div>
<div class="members-section" id="as-student">
  <img src="img/test2.jpg" alt="">
  <span>Join as a student</span>
</div>
<div class="members-section">
  <img src="img/test3,jpg" alt="">
  <span>Upgrade my membership</span>
</div>
<div class="members-section">
  <h5>Teest...</h5>
  <ul class="member-options">
    <li><span>Discounts</span></li>
    <li><span>Institute access</span></li>
    <li><span>Library access</span></li>
    <li><span>Market events</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also note the use of `toggleClass()` means the UI gets a little out of sync on successive clicks. I'd suggest amending the logic if you need that behaviour.

Comment: i want to write click action for as-student id also, in that case it's not working